Why is DateTime.Now returning 4 hours more than my Eastern timezone system time?
I am converting a Blazor Server app to WASM WPA using Visual Studio 2022 Community v 17.10.1.  The apps are virtually identical except for the underlying architecture and some backend code that interfaces with MySql (Server) versus IndexedDB (WASM).
I just noticed that in the WASM app, DateTime.Now is returning 4 hours more than my Eastern time zone system time. The Server app is getting the correct time.
I've tried unsuccessfully to replicate the problem in a newly created WASM WPA app, but it too has the correct time.  My WASM app is running under IIS Express.
